# how to get value of height or width attribute of img tag using xpath at a given position

Tags: xpath, indexing, height, width, image

**For the below XML how to get the value of height or width attribute by giving index.**

```
<root>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non nunc vitae nisl luctus pharetra   at eu nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/pacman10-hp.png"/> Nullam in odio at ligula euismod adipiscing convallis in justo. Donec at massa nulla, at facilisis magna. Integer sit amet elit eu felis venenatis dignissim. In ut mi leo. Suspendisse blandit faucibus fermentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Phasellus ultricies turpis id magna semper vestibulum.
</p>

<p>Quisque blandit pretium libero, venenatis pellentesque purus egestas id. Integer nulla ante, pellentesque eget rhoncus sed, semper vel eros. Nam placerat est et est dictum egestas. Ut gravida blandit lacus rhoncus feugiat. Nunc ut euismod eros. Pellentesque sit amet vehicula mauris. Quisque in nulla quis sapien dictum mattis. Curabitur vehicula lorem ac elit dignissim egestas. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras sit amet tincidunt quam.
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/gabor10-hp.png"/> Ut urna neque, mollis vel tempor placerat, cursus vel enim.
</p>

<p>Praesent gravida dignissim sagittis. Vivamus dictum nisi pulvinar augue vulputate euismod. Vestibulum arcu sapien, laoreet sagittis pulvinar ac, porttitor a tellus.
    <img width="100" height="100" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/d4g_worldcup10_ko-hp.jpg"/> Quisque cursus dignissim libero in convallis. Fusce cursus nisi ut felis feugiat sodales. Praesent nec arcu purus. Donec lorem lectus, tristique eget faucibus sit amet, bibendum nec ipsum. Mauris tempus laoreet tortor non egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus a arcu convallis nibh luctus tempor non quis sem.
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/d4g_worldcup10_uk-hp.jpg"/> Aliquam ac risus velit, ut sodales justo. Ut eget lacus eget nisi hendrerit gravida quis et nibh. Etiam purus felis, fermentum a cursus at, congue vel eros. Aenean semper, sapien eget eleifend fermentum, odio sem tempor dolor, sed porta ligula nunc ac tellus.
</p>

<p>Mauris volutpat nisi vitae sem imperdiet sed ultricies est dictum. Mauris id urna turpis, sit amet rhoncus lectus. Maecenas vitae mi at nulla mattis congue id blandit purus.
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/d4g_worldcup10_nl-hp.jpg"/> Maecenas hendrerit, dui eget faucibus pretium, tellus augue pellentesque metus, id molestie diam arcu ac nibh. Suspendisse sollicitudin viverra blandit. Maecenas sed tellus quis purus bibendum eleifend. Nunc sodales magna id nulla tristique et suscipit purus interdum. Ut at risus quam, nec rutrum risus. Integer ac leo lorem, eget porta nisi. Sed quis lacus dapibus massa commodo ornare. Mauris scelerisque rutrum accumsan. Duis fermentum adipiscing mi eget suscipit. Duis quis nisi libero, iaculis fermentum purus. Etiam risus nibh, tincidunt pellentesque luctus sed, gravida vitae magna.
    <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/d4g_worldcup10_au-hp.jpg"/> Sed laoreet, erat id rutrum dignissim, elit libero fermentum enim, pretium auctor lectus urna vitae nulla. Nullam ante diam, elementum nec elementum quis, consectetur eget arcu.
</p>

<p>Fusce eu nisl risus. Fusce rhoncus iaculis viverra. Curabitur eleifend, nisl sed aliquam dapibus, urna leo scelerisque orci, id commodo dui libero vitae nisi.</p>
<img WIDTH="100" HEIGHT="100" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/d4g_worldcup10_nl-hp.jpg"/>
</root>
```

i tried with

```
//img[1]/@width
```

but not working. Basically i need a XPATH for to get height or width of an img tag irrespective of case(WIDTH or width) and if the width attribute is not available it should return no match or null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
(//img)[$k]/@*[name() = 'width' or name() = 'WIDTH']
```

**Where you need to replace `$k` ith the desired image index**.

This selects the attribute named `"width"` or named `"WIDTH"` of the `$k`-th `img` element in the XML document.

**For example, for the 3rd image use**:

```
(//img)[3]/@*[name() = 'width' or name() = 'WIDTH']
```